# Fontawesome icon vanishes in editor while switching text and visual mode

Tags: tinymce

While switching between text editor mode or updating post fontawesome icon vanishes.Please do not refer to use any plugin.I think i tag is stripped by editor,how can I overcome this?
My code in editor text mode

```
<span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

As long as I am in text mode everything is well but when I switch to visual mode all of my code gets vanish.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic, what have you tried to do so far, maybe hook into `tiny_mce_before_init` ?

Comment: Does this question concern a third party plugin? For example, [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome/)?

Comment: Can't I just skip the plugin.In wp 3.8 and chrome browser vanishes the icon while switching .I have used two plugin.Is there any filter to do without plugin?

Comment: Please provide example of markup that vanishes. Also add more involved details (like code) by editing your question, comments don't handle it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should first enable i tags.Then you should enable class id or span whatever you like.To do so add this code.

```
function add_mce_markup( $initArray ) {
    $ext = 'i[id|name|class|style]';
    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_mce_markup' );
```

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://whtly.com/2014/07/19/prevent-wordpress-tinymce-editor-removing-font-awesome-tags/) help me to fix this issue
Try to inser blank spave `&nbsp;` or comment code `<!--ex-->` in between `i` tag like `<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"><!--tr--></i>` So that wordpress did not recognize it as empty tag.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/189996)